# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError using ButterKnife with Latest Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

I just upgrade my Android Studio today and came across this error when compiling my project using ButterKnife *7.0.2-Snapshot*.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/View
        at butterknife.internal.BindingClass.createBindMethod(BindingClass.java:132)
        at butterknife.internal.BindingClass.brewJava(BindingClass.java:109)
        at butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor.process(ButterKnifeProcessor.java:131)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View
        ... 87 more
```

Anyone else having this issue?  The code has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the error is happening, but downgrading to 7.0.1 allowed the build to compile.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```